# Can not get the readable electron crash reports on Sentry

Tags: electron, crash-reports, sentry

I'm handling crashes in our electron app with crashReporter and sending reports to sentry.io.

The goal is to see which part of JS caused the app to crash. To emulate crash I'm doing "process.crash()". To see source code trace I'm installing sentry from it's documentation, but source code never appears in sentry.

Here is the CrashReporter initialization code:

```
   crashReporter.start({
      companyName: '...',
      productName: '...',
      uploadToServer: true,
      submitURL: 'https://....ingest.sentry.io/api/.../minidump/?sentry_key=...'
    });
```

Sentry is added to project as:

```
sentry-wizard --integration electron
npm install --save-dev @sentry/cli electron-download
node sentry-symbols.js
```

Webpack config:

```
const SentryWebpackPlugin = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin');
var config = {
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(),
    new SentryWebpackPlugin({
      include: '.',
      ignoreFile: '.sentrycliignore',
      ignore: ['node_modules', 'webpack.config.js'],
      configFile: 'sentry.properties'
    })
  ],
  ...
```

But this is how it looks on sentry:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are producing a native crash, what you see here is a C++ stack trace which is symbolicated. Try to `throw new Error('test');` in JavaScript somewhere, then you should see a JS stack trace.

Comment: Native crash is exactly what we are trying to catch and trace to our source code. What you proposing will emit not a native crash but simple JS exception, it will not cause app to crash.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question then. Sentry is also not able right now to tell you which JS frame caused a native crash (combining the stack traces).

Comment: Well, that sounds pretty much necessary for the crash reporting. Maybe you can suggest something instead of Sentry which can do that?